# How do I share a menu definition between a context menu and a regular menu in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a defined MenuItem that I would like to share between two different menus on one page. The menu contains functionallity that is the same between both menus and I do not want two copies of it. Is there anyway to define a MenuItem in the Page.Resources and reference it in the ContextMenu XAML below?

```
<Page.Resources>
    <MenuItem x:Key="123"/>
</Page.Resources>

<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem>Something hardcoded</MenuItem>

    <!-- include shared menu here -->

</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this by setting x:Shared="False" on the menu item itself. Resources are shared between each place that uses them by default (meaning one instance across all uses), so turning that off means that a new "copy" of the resource is made each time.

So:

```
<MenuItem x:Key="myMenuItem" x:Shared="False" />
```

You'll still get a "copy" of it, but you only need to define it in one place. See if that helps. You use it like this within your menu definition:

```
<StaticResource ResourceKey="myMenuItem" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to mix-and-match... I would make a custom control that inherits from ContextMenu that has a "SharedMenuItems" Dependancy Property and a MenuItems Dependancy Property. This way your control can decide how to merge these two sets together. If you would like an example of this, please let me know.

Comment: While this didn't answer my exact question, it seems like a good work around. I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues.. I could post code/xaml to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A number of options:
a) Databind the ContextMenu or the Menu to the same underlying collection and use item templates et al to the work
b) Use commands, and databind to a set of command bindings