# XAML - StaticResources in Collection Initializers

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection, static-resource

I want to add a single model object that has been instantiated *once* in XAML, and add it to two different collections (in xaml).

The following code renders fine in Blend's Design Time, but I get the following errors at run time:

*For "Post1"*
Object of type 'WpfBlog.Models.Tag' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[WpfBlog.Models.Tag]'.  Error at object 'WpfBlog.Admin' in markup file 'WpfBlog;component/Admin.xaml' Line XX Position YY.

*If I comment out "Post1", I'll get this error on "Post2"*
Cannot add element to property 'Tags', because the property can have only one child element if it uses an explicit collection tag.  Error at object 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' in markup file 'WpfBlog;component/Admin.xaml' Line AA Position BB.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:Tag x:Key="TDD" Name="TDD" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White" />
    <model:Tag x:Key="Agile" Name="Agile" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black" />
    <model:Tag x:Key="Waterfail" Name="Waterfail" ForeColor="Red" BackColor="White" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:AdminViewModel>
        <local:AdminViewModel.AllTags>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="TDD"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Agile"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Waterfail"/>
        </local:AdminViewModel.AllTags>
        <local:AdminViewModel.Posts>
            <local:PostViewModel Title="Post1">
                <local:PostViewModel.Tags>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="TDD" />
                </local:PostViewModel.Tags>
            </local:PostViewModel>
            <local:PostViewModel Title="Post2">
                <local:PostViewModel.Tags>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="TDD" />
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Agile" />
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Waterfail" />
                </local:PostViewModel.Tags>
            </local:PostViewModel>
        </local:AdminViewModel.Posts>
    </local:AdminViewModel>
<Window.DataContext>
```

The following code compiles and runs fine, but two tags named "TDD" get created, so if I try to rename the tag, I have to do it for all of the posts, instead of just the one Tag object.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:Tag x:Key="TDD" Name="TDD" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White" />
    <model:Tag x:Key="Agile" Name="Agile" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black" />
    <model:Tag x:Key="Waterfail" Name="Waterfail" ForeColor="Red" BackColor="White" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:AdminViewModel>
        <local:AdminViewModel.AllTags>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="TDD"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Agile"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Waterfail"/>
        </local:AdminViewModel.AllTags>
        <local:AdminViewModel.Posts>
            <local:PostViewModel Title="Post1">
                <local:PostViewModel.Tags>
                    <model:Tag Name="TDD" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White" />
                </local:PostViewModel.Tags>
            </local:PostViewModel>
            <local:PostViewModel Title="Post2">
                <local:PostViewModel.Tags>
                    <model:Tag Name="TDD" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White" />
                    <model:Tag Name="Agile" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black" />
                    <model:Tag Name="Waterfail" ForeColor="Red" BackColor="White" />
                </local:PostViewModel.Tags>
            </local:PostViewModel>
        </local:AdminViewModel.Posts>
    </local:AdminViewModel>
<Window.DataContext>
```

Any ideas? I'd be able to ignore it and work around it if Blend didn't render it correctly, but it does!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to avoid the problem by explicitly initializing a new collection within the Tags property. Something like this:

```
<local:PostViewModel Title="Post1">
  <local:PostViewModel.Tags>
     <model:TagCollection>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="TDD" />
     </model:TagCollection>
  </local:PostViewModel.Tags>
```

Obviously, this is only possible if you allow your Tags property to be writable.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150150/how-do-i-share-a-menu-definition-between-a-context-menu-and-a-regular-menu-in-w#150706), I think.

The solution should be to add an x:Shared="False" attribute to your <model:Tag> elements. That tells WPF not to share a single instance each time one is referenced, and instead to create new instances of them.